# Python string to unicode fails

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file with the following line:

> raúl fernando sendic rodríguez is the leader of uruguay .

I am reading the file doing:

```
l = open(file_name).read().split()
```

And I get:

> ['ra\xc3\xbal', 'fernando', 'sendic', 'rodr\xc3\xadguez', 'is', 'the', 'leader', 'of', 'uruguay', '.']

I want to convert it to a unicode string with the `u` in the begining, but so far I tried:

```
print list(map(lambda a: unicode(a, "utf-8"), l))
print list(map(lambda a: a.decode('utf-8'), l))
```

And got (same for both):

> [u'ra\xfal', u'fernando', u'sendic', u'rodr\xedguez', u'is', u'the', u'leader', u'of', u'uruguay', u'.']

How can I properly decode that string as unicode?

Note: This is python 2.7

Comment: There's nothing wrong with those strings. They just aren't printed the way you expected. Try `print(u'ra\xfal')` and you'll get `raúl` as output.

Comment: You are right, that is actually more interesting... why does printing an array of strings different than just the strings?

Comment: The `print` function calls `str` on the value. A list's `str` function calls `repr` on all its elements. So `print([u'ra\xfal'])` prints the string in the same way `print(repr(u'ra\xfal'))` would.